# Google аутентификация

Tags: java, android, firebase

Делаю аутентификацию для гугла через firebase, после выбора email ничего не происходит. В консоли 2 ошибки:

> E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>
> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Comment: Как именно вы делаете аутентификацию (код)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это довольно распространенная ошибка клавиатуры, просто поменяйте `android:inputType="..."` на `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` или `android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"`.

Также это можно организовать и через этот способ тоже:

```
mInputField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Ссылка [на источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)

Comment: Это только в EditText емейла поменять, или все  ?

Comment: В параметрах EditText ( XML ) найти строку android:inputType="..." и просто поменять android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" или android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions".

Comment: В параметрах какого именно EditText ? Эта ошибка возникает при нажатии на кнопку аутентификации гугла.

Comment: измените KeyboardType

Comment: Как и где, обясните поподропней.

Comment: Из настроек самого телефона попробуйте изменить тип клавиатуры.

Comment: Если и после этого не получится скиньте код, посмотрю